# What is this plant that resembles tomato and has small dark fruit?

Tags: identification, volunteer

I got lazy and let weeds takeover a bed near the porch that has some azaleas and perennials. When I went to pull some of the weeds, I noticed this ~3ft high plant that looks like a tomato plant. It is starting to fruit and has very small dark, almost black, fruits.

Is this some kind of tomato?

[image: Leaves, flowers and stalk resemble tomato plants.]

[image: small dark fruits]

Comment: In the first photo, there are leaves with serrated edges, but I can't tell whether they are from the same plant - the leaves in the rest of the photos are blurry, but the edges appear smooth. Could you please describe the leaves and flowers?

Comment: @michelle I'm not the questioner; however, I can't say for sure either, but some Solanum berries have leaves like the one in the second picture. I think there are multiple kinds of plants in the first picture. Some of the blurry ones that seem serrated might not be, and may be a different plant from the clearly serrated ones.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That looks a lot to me like one of the [*Solanum nigrum*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solanum_nigrum) ("black nightshade") varieties -- see the "Solanum nigrum complex" paragraph under "Taxonomy" in the Wikipedia article.

I'm not sure where you're from, but they grow as weeds all over North America, as well as -- as far as I know -- most of the rest of the world. They are not tomatoes, and most of these varieties are very dangerous.*

The leaves are smooth and kite-shaped with wavy margins and prominent veins. The berries are clustered and spherical, 1/4" diameter or a bit more at full growth, and turn from green to shiny black as they ripen. The flowers are white and five-petaled, with prominent yellow "beaks" in the center (technically, *anthers*) . (Personally, I think they're fairly handsome plants.)

It is *related* to the tomato, as well as several other food plants -- eggplants, capiscums, and potatoes. This accounts for the vague similarites one can see in the fruit and the leaf structures. They are all members of *Solanaceae*, the "nightshade family".

Some parts of different varieties of this genus and species *are reported* to have different degrees of edibility, depending on you, the plant, the ripeness of the berries, how you cook it, the day of the week, and whether your car is red.

***Please don't eat*** any part of this plant unless you get a *much better* identification from an actual botanist or someone who can see the plant first-hand and is verifiably an expert.**

---

*Among non-mushrooms, poisonous nightshades are probably second only to the poisonous hemlocks ("poison hemlock" and the "water hemlock" genus) in terms of deadliness.

**Actually, that goes for any wild plant. Most aren't poisonous, and most of the poisonous ones aren't automatically deadly, but why make yourself sick for curiousity when there's plenty of books you can check first? Many of the poisonous wild ones are closely related to our food plants -- like this one, and various members of the pea family.

Answer (score 11):

I'd +10 @Bamboo's comment on Brian's answer, if I could: "*ID is important*".  Anyone thinking about eating the berries of something similar should be **sure** that they don't have **[Deadly Nightshade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atropa_belladonna)**, "one of the most toxic plants found in the Western Hemisphere".  After giving our daughter ipecac for eating nightshade berries long ago, I always pull up anything that looks like this.  I'm sure there are similar plants that are fine; I don't think it's a good idea to have them around to provoke a possibly fatal mistake.  Birds spread these around quite a bit (the berries aren't toxic to birds), so if you have it, your neighbor probably will too, sooner or later.  Two to five nightshade berries are lethal to children.

Comment: Although not 100% sure, I agree with the Nightshade diagnosis. There are many varieties, and they are closely related to tomato, pepper, and potato - hence the similarities in leaf, flower, seed. Pull it out, and discard of it in a safe manner. You may also want to use gloves (from memory I believe some nightshades have saps that can sensitize skin). Even if it is a potato gone to seed (those leaves don't look like potato to me), this is the best course of action just in case.

Answer (score 3):

The fruit looks like that of *[Solanum melanocerasum](http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=Solanum%20melanocerasum)* or more commonly *Garden Huckleberry*.

**Removed comments on eating them just to be safe.**

After looking into this more I found *[Solanum burbankii](http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=Solanum%20burbankii)*, or more commonly *Wonderberry*, as another edible variety that looks the same as garden huckleberry.

In any case I'd avoid eating them as others have said since it's not known what variety they are and it's probably best to pull them as well. If you would like an edible variety a pack of seeds costs a few dollars and is well worth the purchase to know that you're getting a safe variety.

Comment: If they are garden huckleberry, the flowers should have five white petals with a brown part in the centre that sticks out. Don't think they're potato, the fruits on that are the size of cherry tomatoes and not usually black. ID is important, many Solanum fruits are toxic..

Comment: I bought Garden Huckleberry seeds. They grew, flowered, set fruit. So unimpressive that it wasn't worth taking the risk that they could somehow be mixed up with a poisonous variety. They really are just scraggly plants with nice leaves, tiny potato flowers, little shiny black fruits. Nothing special. I experimented.

Comment: They don't scream Wonderberry to me. I've grown Wonderberries a few times. The fruits of the pictured plant are too shiny, and the calyxes too attached, but yes, they do look to be in the same genus or family (but are probably toxic, although I have my doubts about them being deadly to full-sized adult humans who aren't allergic).

Answer (score 2):

These grow wild under my pine trees, some people around here say either their kids or their animals eat the black berries, others say they should be avoided at all costs. I confused them for Belladonna aka Deadly Nightshade, but I researched that it doesn't grow on the wild around here, but I read in a local source for anything related to atropa belladona and found out that a very close relative does grow around here. I tried the black berries, ate 5 - 10 of them, and they seem to have a mild sedative effect. Leaf-eating worms seem to love them, so I try to avoid mowing them down when I cut the grass as a means of protecting my potatoes, since it looks like both white flies and caterpillars much prefer these over the potato leaves.

Comment: A picture of your plants/berries could be helpful if you can get one.

Answer (score 0):

Those arnt the belladonna deadly nightshade, those are edible as long as you eat the black ones not the green ones much the same as how you shouldn't eat green potatoes because of the toxins. They were introduced into Australia as well during the golderush era as vegetables.

Comment: Can you tell us the name of the plant so that we can search details about its edibility?

Comment: Nick, welcome to Gardening SE! We appreciate your contribution and hope you will like it here. There’s a favor I have to ask from you: *Especially* when claiming that something is edible but there’s a chance of a plant being toxic or confused with something dangerous, giving a precise id, ideally with both Latin and common name, and *the characteristics that help distinguish between them* is highly recommend. Note that future readers with a similar plant will read this Q/A. Could you [edit] your post, please?

Answer (score -1):

I grew up thinking this was poisonous and could die if I eat them, but also grew up with the temptation of what they taste like, finally I tried them, in Phoenix, AZ. Today 10/24/2023. The green ones have a nasty taste and do feel like poisonous to me. However the black ones in the contrary are sweet and have like a fruit flavor to me. I don’t recommend eating them if not sure. However I had to try myself, I probably will be eating the black ones from now on, if in case this have a negative impact I will post it, and on my next doctors visit, I will let my doctor know in case he needs to do blood work to see if that had any impact in my body, or bad impact more like, and will post whatever doctor comes up with. Personally it didn’t feel like anything bad with the ripped black ones, and those are the ones I will continue eating until I find out if I shouldn’t eat them, like someone in the comments said they were toxic. I grew up thinking they were poisonous, but at the same time with the feeling of wanting to try them and see what they taste like. Not recommending anyone to try them, just sharing my own personal experience and if I get confirmation that are not eadible, I will post ass soon as I get that from a professional too.

Comment: Hi Sergio, please post a picture of the plant and berries so it can be identified

Comment: Hi Sergio, this site works differently. We expect answers in this section. And the question was to identify the plant.